# Python Input() function causes execution to pause for multithreaded applications

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I created two threads and I want to process in one of the threads while the other one waits for user input.

However, in Python, the input() function causes execution on the other thread to stop while waiting for input. Here is a simplified situation:

```
import thread
import time

def print_statements():
    for i in range(500):
        print "Print number " + str(i)

def get_input():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    input_value = input("Please enter a number")

thread.start_new_thread( print_statements, () )
thread.start_new_thread( get_input, () )
```

In this code, it prints to about "print number 50", then it waits for "Please enter a number", until the number is entered, it will NOT continue the processing (printing) in the other thread.

Is there a way to get around this to do processing in one thread, while waiting for input in another.

Thanks

Comment: how are you running this?

Comment: Using IDLE and Python 2.7

Comment: You are running exactly as posted? Pretty sure this is an idle problem not python

Comment: idle does not work well with threads, print is not thread-safe. If you run from the command line does it work as expected?

Comment: I would also use `raw_input` when using python2

Comment: This is almost certainly an IDLE problem. You should also probably use the `threading` module instead of the `thread` module (as the docs suggest).

Comment: I know this an old post but i have the same issue using the same version did you find a solution?

Comment: @J.Clarke Yes, this issue was a problem for IDLE and not Python itself. Try running it in a command prompt window, and it will work as expected. For my actual application, this issue did not show up, only when running in IDLE.

Comment: @Yasir Thanks, i already solved this for myself but it is still really annoying for debugging.